# How to keep the toolbar on top of the page only want the page scroll pass certain height or element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I know how to keep the toolbar on top of the page when scrolling, however, I see the website http://seekingalpha.com/ which has a toolbar that remains on top only when the page scroll pass the header part (which is on top of the toolbar). This feature is really cool but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ym2Ga/75/

Answer (score 0):

I am going to use the same page as an example:

**Javascript**

You are going to need the relative position of element to the window;

```
var toolbar = document.getElementById('nav_container_wrap');
var bounds = toolbar.getBoundingClientRect();
```

bounds object contains these data:

> bottom: 134 height: 32 left: -1 right: 1287 top: 102 width: 1288

Next, you will have some event listener to listen scroll event and check top value of this element:

```
window.onscroll = function (event) {
  // called when the window is scrolled.
  var bounds = toolbar.getBoundingClientRect();
  if(bounds.top < 0) {
    //add class to the element here
    toolbar.className = toolbar.className + " top_nav_fixed";
  }
}
```

So, when the top value goes bellow zero - you have to set position to fixed (for example using this class):

```
.top_nav_fixed {
   position: fixed !important;
   top: 0px !important;
   left: -2px !important;
   right: -1px !important;
   border-top: 0px !important;
   z-index: 49 !important;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var toolbar = $('#nav_container_wrap');

$(window).scroll(function() { //when window is scrolled
    var bounds = toolbar.offset();
    if(bounds.top - $(window).scrollTop() < 0){
       $('#nav_container_wrap').addClass('top_nav_fixed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the live example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72Uxv/1/). The general idea is to get the page position from which the element should be attached to window and when scroll position exceeds that value, you set the element to have fixed position. If scroll position is lower than calculated or hardcoded value (element_position), then you set it back to default value - static.

**jQuery code**

```
element_position = $("#nav").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scroll_position >= element_position)
    {
        $("#nav").css("position", "fixed");
    } else {
        $("#nav").css("position", "static");
    }
});
```